# How to refresh a GoogleMap instance within gmapsfx (in Java)?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am searching for a way to refresh the display of an instance of GoogleMap within gmapsfx.

This is primarily to remove markers from the displayed map that have been removed from the map instance (they disappear once the map has been zoomed or panned).

The markers are added with

```
map.addMarker();
```

and removed with

```
map.removeMarker( markerInstance );
```

I would imagine that this must be around somewhere...  any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: use `marker.setMap(null);` instead and then set map again with the marker inside panned area with `marker.setMap(map);`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me; marker.setMap() is protected within gmapsfx.  The call to map.removeMarker(marker) is a wrapper that calls marker.setMap(null).

Comment: oh alright, thanks for the explanation. But do you call setMap(map) in some way after?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Once you clear map of all the markers, in javascript you would have to set the map again with the markers in the panned area. You just cleared the map, if there's no subsequent command to set the map again, it will be an empty canvas. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was provided to perform a refresh by changing the zoom level to another value then back again.

```
//  Force an update by changing the zoom level in the background
int currentZoom = map.getZoom();
map.setZoom( currentZoom - 1 );
map.setZoom( currentZoom );
```